# debian 8.2 can no longer su to root

Tags: debian, sudo, root, authentication

If I try to "su root" with an incorrect password, I get the expected 'authentication failure'.

If I try to with the *correct* password, I get 'setgid: Operation not permitted"

I have tried the usual 'boot via grub to reset the root password, but then I get 'bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device' and need to power cycle for the keyboard even to be recognized.

I do not have sudo installed. I have not made any administrative changes to this machine in months, it was working as expected, and now suddenly is not.

This machine dual boots with Windows, and the root correct password does allow me to access the shared Windows hard drive. ("Authentication required to mount...blah blah..")

edit:
ls -l $(which su) shows

-rwxr-xr-x 1 myname myname 40168 Nov 20 2014 /bin/su

SOLVED:

Eventually I determined that I could not su to any user, not only to root.

Booted from a live CD

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt    *(sda1 in my case, maybe not yours)*

chown -R root:root etc

chown -R root:root bin

..all the other directories that were accidentally mine, not root's

and most importantly, /bin/su needed to be *-rwsr-xr-x*

it was not just the ownership, but the 's', not 'x' for the owner that was tripping things up.

I suspect other issues will arise from incorrect ownership, but now that I can su to root I should be able to correct them.

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -l $(which su)`

Comment: Your edit doesn't show the *whole* output of `ls -l $(which su)`, we need to check user and group... please add the whole output.

Comment: I have an elderly Ubuntu CD that I can try booting from to change permissions. Am I liable to run into issues due to this being a dual boot with Windows PC? I don't want to break that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies within the permissions of your su binary, which need to be:
`-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 35200 Mai 25  2012 /bin/su`.
(checked on Wheezy and Jessie).

This mostly happens when you acidentially change owner and group of your whole filesystem or a subfolder like `bin`.

To get `su` to work again, you can either `aptitude reinstall login` or boot from another medium and fix the permissions from there.

Comment: Remember that you need to be root though...

Comment: But I am not root, and apparently cannot become root. Catch 22.

Comment: I notice that I have ownership of /etc/passwd and /etc/group, but since the problem does not appear to be root's password, I don't think that helps me any.

Comment: That's why I wrote to boot from another medium and change permissions from there.

Comment: If you have ownership of `/etc/passwd` and other files, you most probably have messed up the permissions of you whole system.

Comment: No idea how it happened, but having booted from a CD, I see that the ownership of /mnt/bin, /mnt/boot, /mnt/etc, /mnt/dev, /mnt/lib, and /mnt/lib64 are all 1000:1000. Comparing to another system, it looks like these should normally all be root:root. Is there any reason not to simply "chown -r root:root /mnt" ?

Comment: That's a different question...

Comment: "That's a different question" Presumably meaning "I don't know. At your own risk." Thanks. Having apparently already shot myself in one foot, I may as well go for the other too.

Comment: Meaning "Please open a new question and I'll answer there".